# How can I automatically invoke a method using a constructor

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript prototype object, with a function defined. Is it possible to have the function invoked when constructing the prototype?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
function Proto(){

function invoke(){
console.log("I am invoked");
}


}

var proto = new Proto()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make it an IIFE:

```
function Proto(){
  (function invoke(){
    console.log("I am invoked");
  })();
}
```

Or you could just call it in the constructor function:

```
function Proto(){

  function invoke(){
    console.log("I am invoked");
  }

  invoke();
}

var proto = new Proto()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure what you mean by "IIFE" can you please explain me what that means?

Comment: Apologies, it's an "immediately-invoked function expression." Useful for a lot of different things-- nice to have to encapsulate scope as well. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression Truly, it's the `();` at the end that matters: that is invoking it immediately.

Comment: Ahh. Now I see. I saw that on some API's i was working on and never really understood the concept. But now I understand. Thank you!